# Question concerning derivatives in an interval

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Suppose $f$ is differentiable in the interval $[a,b]$, with $f(a)f(b)<0$ and $\forall \ x \in [a,b]$, $0<A \leq |f'(x)|$ and $|f''(x)| \leq M$. Prove $f$ is either increasing or decreasing.

What I thought to do was suppose $f$ is neither increasing or decreasing and $f(a)>0, f(b)<0$, then must exist $x_1,x_2$ such that $f'(x_1)<0$, and $f'(x_2)>0$, in any other case $f$ would be either increasing, decreasing or constant. As $f'(x_1)<0<f'(x_2)$, by Darboux theorem, must exist a $c \in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f'(c)=0$, against the initial hypothesis. If $f$ is increasing in this case, it would not be possible to have $f(b)<0$.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I'm currently editing

Comment: By the way, you should check if the statement is correct or not. Indeed, the assumptions $f(a)f(b)<0$ and $|f''(x)|\leq M$ don't seem useful here...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe what do you think now? I agree with you |″()|≤ doesn't helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0 <A \leq |f'(x)|$ for every $x \in [a,b]$, then $f'(x) \neq 0$.

Moreover, since $f$ is twice differentiable, then $f'$ is continuous.

By the IVT (or Darboux if you don't want to use the fact that $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$), one deduces that either $f'(x) < 0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$, or $f'(x) > 0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$, and hence, $f$ is either decreasing or increasing.

Comment: I found a problem, using Darboux theorem, why can you assume that exists $x_1,x_2$, with $x_1<x_2$ such that $f'(x_1)<0$ and $f'(x_2)>0$?

Comment: okay, it doesn't matter if you pick $x_1<x_2$ or $x_2<x_1$.